# EAGLE Schematic connection check (USB C)

Tags: power, pcb, eaglecad, usb-c, data

I'm a beginner in PCB designing and I want to use a USB C port on my custom PCB for powering and data. For this purpose, I have created below schematic in EAGLE.

My questions are:

1. I connected DN1 and DP1 pins for data transfer, should I also connect pin DP2 and DN2 to DP1 and DN1 respectively so that USB can be connected in any orientation?
2. Should I connect my SHIELD pin to ground or leave it open ? I saw some PCB schematics and found that they put a cross at Shield pin and sometime they connected it to ground. I'm confused now.
3. Here I have used PRTR5V0U2F for ESD protection and have connected pin 3 to GND and pin 5 to V_USB_ZED. (I saw this connection on an open source project and tried to connect it similarly). But other places I have seen pin 3 of PRTR5V0U2F connected to power and pin 5 connected to GND? Are both of these connections fine?
4. I want to connect VBUS of USB-C to V_USB_ZED, will this connection be correct and will my schematic correct?
5. I don't know the functioning of SBUS1 and SBUS2 pins, as my application is to get 5V DC in and data transfer, should I connect  SBUS1 and SBUS2 pins to GND or leave them open?
   [image]